# PHP input vars exceed 1000 - Is it an issue?

Tags: php, jquery, html

The reason I have so many input variables is because I have a lot of repeated "input" and "select" forms.  Every row of my table creates an identical form, and I use jQuery to change the name of the forms on just one row to edit at a time.  The end result is that I have 1000's of input forms with name=Category, and 1 input form with name=CategoryEdit.

When I var_dump my $_POST array, it's not particularly long.  However because of all the repetition of forms with the same name, I can get over 10,000 input forms which triggers the warning.  My question is just is this a problem?  Or is it sort of a false warning due to my bad coding, but won't really cause problems?

Comment: do you mean input *fields*?

Comment: The PHP error is "Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000."  Which I believe is triggered by all my input fields.  Is there a difference or is it semantics?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a false warning, it will definitely hinder performance. If they appear in the $_POST they are getting processed to some degree

Comment: It's not insignificant.  Do you actually have thousands of forms, or thousands of fields within a form? You really need to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: you're hitting max_input_vars (http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars), which you can increase if you wish, but I can't help but think a redesign of how you handle this would be better :) From the manual: "If there are more input variables than specified by this directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are truncated from the request."

Comment: Sorry for the bad terminology.  I only have 1 form (POST) for the entire page.  I have thousands of fields within a form.  They are only appearing once in the $_POST because they all have the same name, so presumably $_POST just takes the value of the last one.

Comment: as @RobGudgeon said, you are likely to run into performance problems;  you might consider a redesign

Comment: 10,000 fields for a user is insane